# Finding directories named "archive" and deleting files

Tags: perl, shell, system-administration

I have a requirement to delete all files in directories named "archive" older than X days. There are multiple directories named "archive" located in various depths of the directory tree.

My question is what tool to use to find the directories? My first impulse is to use the Perl `File:Find` module, but I have been embarrassed in the past finding out a shell script one-liner to do the same thing that I have written a multi-line Perl script for.

Comment: Have you looked at the aptly named `find` yet?

Comment: Sure have, but find doesn't support wildcarding of the directory path. For example /path/*/archive/*. So I would have to declare the full path for every archive directory in the tree, close to 100 and growing.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this will work for you:

```
# Delete one at a time.
find /path/to/your/files* -type f -mtime +10 -exec rm {} \;

# Use one rm for multiple dirs. (GNU find)
find /path/to/your/files* -type f -mtime +10 -exec rm {} +

# Use one rm for multiple dirs. (Any find)
find /path/to/your/files* -type f -mtime +10 -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

In this case it will delete all files from your path, that are older than 10 days. Use it with care. :-)

If you just want to delete files in the folder archive you should add

```
-ipath '*/archive/*'
```

to

```
find /path/to/your/files* -ipath '*/archive/*' -type f -mtime +10 -exec rm {} \;
```

Maybe you should test the whole scenario by writing the found files into a textfile just to be sure it is correct.

```
find /path/to/your/files* -ipath '*/archive/*' -type f -mtime +10 > filelist.txt
```

Comment: Instead of launching one `rm` process for every object, use the `+` terminator in lieu of `\;`.  This will cause multiple arguments to be bundled to each instantiation.  Your process table, your processor, and your users will appreciate you, and for large numbers of files, you will see grand speed improvements.

Comment: @ikegami I added the missing argument. :-)

Comment: Oliver, looks great but it seems that the -ipath option is not supported in the find on AIX systems

Comment: @clmccomas, Does it support `-path`? That would do the trick too.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the `Path::Class` module, which has a `traverse` method that is similar to the way `File::Find` works, but with a lot more convenience.

This program will search through the given directory tree and find all files that are in a folder named `archive` and have a modification time of three days or more ago.

As it stands the program will simply print the files it finds that match the criteria. To actually remove them you should delete the `#` comment delimiter from the line containing `$node->remove`.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Path::Class;

my $dir = dir '/path/to/root';

$dir->traverse(sub {
  my ($node, $cont) = @_;
  if ($node->is_dir) {
    $cont->();
  }
  elsif ($node->dir->basename eq 'archive') {
    my $age = (time - $node->stat->mtime) / (60 * 60 * 24);
    printf "%s %.1f days old\n", $node, $age;
    # $node->remove if $age > 3;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work on Linux and Macs:

```
$ find . -name archive -type d -mtime -$X_DAYS -delete
```

However, my preference would be to first run this:

```
$ find . -name archive -type d -mtime -$X_DAYS -ls | tee find.out
```

That will list the files you're thinking of deleting and put them in a file called `find.out`. You can look at the output and make sure that there's nothing in there that will cause any problems. Maybe there is an archive directory older than 10 days, but you don't want to remove it.

You can edit this file to remove anything that you want to keep. Then you can run the following command:

```
$ awk '{print "rm -rf " $NF}' find.out | tee command.out
```

This will create a file of commands to delete the directories. Take a look at `command.out` and if everything is in order, then do this:

$ sh command.out

Why go through all of this rigamarole? Because you want to make sure you're deleting what you want to delete and not what you want to keep. Better take a few extra steps and make sure everything is okay if you're deleting stuff.